# Computing canonical sheaf

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am learning about canonical sheaf. I am struggling with computing the canonical sheaf of:

1. Del pezzo surface $X$: I know that such surface is either $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ or the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at most $8$ points. But I do not know how to compute the canonical sheaf of $X$.
2. I know that if $X=H_1\cap ...\cap H_r$ is the complete intersection of codimension $r$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ with $\deg\, H_i =d_i$ then the canonical sheaf of $X$ is $\mathcal{O}_X(d_1+\cdots+d_r -n -1)$. Why this is true?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the blow up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ iin $k$ points t is $-3 \pi^*H + E_1 \ldots + E_{k}$ ($H$ is the hyperplane class, $\pi$ is the blow down map to $\mathbb{P}^2$, $E_k$ are the exceptional divisors).

This follows from a general fact that the canonical divisor of $KBl_{p}(S) = \pi^*{K_S} + E$ where is the exceptional divisor and the on $\mathbb{P}^2$ the canonical sheaf is $-3H$ (which in turn follows from the Euler sequence on projective space).

For $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ it is $-2 (\mathbb{P}^1 \times \{p_0\} + \{p_0\} \times \mathbb{P}^1)$.

For complete intersections the formula follows from the adjunction formula (applied $r$ times each time getting a formula for the intersecion with a hypersurface).

In all of the descriptions above I am implicitly using the correspondane between divisors and locally free sheaves.

All these facts can be found in an introductory graduate text in algebraic geometry. I recommend "complex algebraic surfaces" by Beauville.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and a good reference. I write down the case of complete intersection as following: Since $H_1$ is in codimension 1 then by adjunction formula we have $\omega_{H_1}=\omega_{\mathbb{P}^n} \otimes \mathcal{O}(H_1)\otimes \mathcal{O}_{H_1}=\mathcal{O}_{H_1}(d_1-n-1)$. Now apply the formula again for $H_1\cap H_2$ this give $\omega_{H_1\cap H_2}=\omega_{H_1} \otimes \mathcal{O}_{H_1}(H_1.H_2)\otimes \mathcal{O}_{H_1 \cap H_2}.$ Can you explain for me why $\mathcal{O}_{H_1}(H_1.H_2) \cong \mathcal{O}_{H_1}(d_2)$ ?? Do you have any suggest for me to the case $P^1\times P^1$